# Multiple consumers in same consumer group

Tags: python, apache-kafka, consumer, producer

I have 1 producer and 1 consumers in the same group (my-group).

```
# To send messages asynchronously
producer = SimpleProducer(kafka, async=True)
producer.send_messages("my-topic", "async message")

# To consume messages, consumer1
consumer1 = SimpleConsumer(kafka, "my-group", "my-topic")
for message in consumer1:
    print(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleConsumer doesn't support consumer groups, you should use KafkaConsumer instead.